# What happens on server when I catch a SocketException for a Timeout on client?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sockets, tcplistener

I'm developing a socket server and a client with .NET Framework 4.6.2 and C#.

On server I do a operation in a database (update a table using a stored procedure).

On client I send a data to update on database.

Every thing works fine until I get a socket exception on client due to a TimeOut. After that, I get errors on database updates. The stored procedure doesn't fail but it doesn't its work. In other words, it returns 0 because I have checked in the stored procedure that the row has been updated but the row hasn't been update:

```
set @commFlag = (Select CommissioningFlag from Code where CodeId = @codeId);

if (@commFlag = @newCommFlagValue)
begin
    return 0;
end
else
    return -1;
```

Here, stored procedure returns 0, but if I do `Select CommissioningFlag from Code where CodeId = @codeId` on SSMS it returns the previous value of `CommissioningFlag`.

I have fixed this problem doing a reset on client side when I get a Timeout SocketException:

```
private SynchronousSocketClient trzCodeReceiverClient;

[ ... ]
try
{
    trzCodeReceiverClient.SendData(dataFrame, out dataReceived);
}
catch (SocketException ex)
{
    dataReceived = Resources.ErrorSocketTrzCodeReceiver;

    RestartSocket();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    dataReceived = Resources.ErrorSocketTrzCodeReceiver;

    RestartSocket();
}
```

And `RestartSocket` method:

```
private void RestartSocket()
{
    if (trzCodeReceiverClient != null)
        trzCodeReceiverClient.EndConnection();

    NameValueCollection section =
        ConfigurationManager.GetSection("TRZCodeReceiverSection") as NameValueCollection;

    string trzCodeReceiverHost = section["host"];
    int trzCodeReceiverPort = int.Parse(section["port"]);
    int receiveTimeOut = int.Parse(section["receiveTimeOut"]);

    trzCodeReceiverClient = new SynchronousSocketClient(
                    trzCodeReceiverHost,
                    trzCodeReceiverPort,
                    receiveTimeOut);

    trzCodeReceiverClient.EstablishConnection();
}
```

`SynchronousSocketClient` is this [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/kb5kfec7(v=vs.110).aspx).

But I think this is not the right way to do it. I don't want to do a `RestartSocket`. Maybe server it's in an unstable state after a Timeout or I don't know.

Do you know what is happening here?

I think that the problem could be that I don't wait to receive the response from server because I `SocketException` is thrown.

Server class is more or less like this [one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: *I have checked in the stored procedure that the row has been updated but the row hasn't been update* could you clarify this sentence?

Comment: @Default Yes, I have added after that sentence the piece of SQL code that does that.

Comment: Can you include the source code of your server-side listener? How TCP/IP handles closing can be a little tricky.

Comment: The timeout you're getting shouldn't be caused by the SendData-method unless you modified the class to change the SendTimeout-property? (the default is an infinite time-out period). Instead, it could be SqlCommand which causes the exception since its timeout by default is 30 seconds: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx (I'd also personally switch to a standard solution like httpclient and owin server, but that's another discussion:-)). This should easily be determined by a try-catch on your server.

Comment: @Dag Where can I find more information about HttpClient and Owin Server? The problem here is that we are using Cognex's Cameras and they only use sockets (I think). I have developed a socket client to simulate Cognex's cameras. The timeout is due to stored procedure, it gets sometime more time to do its work. SqlCommand is inside a try-catch also. And I change `Socket.ReceiveTimeout`, it is not using its default value. The value I set depends on the test I'm doing because sometimes I'm testing with a `ReceiveTimeout` of 6 seconds to avoid this exception.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how your setup looks like. Is the camera TCP/IP-enabled, so the client is communicating with both a camera -and- a server running SQL server?

Comment: @Dag The camera is communicating with a socket server (a Windows Service). That socket server will receive the data from the camera, execute a stored procedure with that data, and return a message through the socket indicating that a row with that data has been updated or no. Sometimes, this update operation gets more time to execute and on the camera we get a SocketException due to a TimeOut. But the confirmation message has been sent to the camera and I think that the problem is that: there is an unread message on the socket.

Comment: Can you instead save the data from the camera in a staging table, and run the stored proc periodically against this table? The idea is to let the camera "off the hook" as soon as possible to prevent it from timing out, and run the stored procedure periodically in a separate thread/process.